# Confusion about homogeneous spaces associated to a cocycle $\xi$ and its localization $\xi_v$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, elliptic-curves, homogeneous-spaces

I have a slight confusion about Selmer group and homogeneous spaces $WC(E/K)$. I am using Silverman's book *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*. First, there is this commutative diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>>
E'(K) / \phi(E(K)) @>\delta_0>> 
H^1(G_{\bar K / K}, E[\phi]) @>wc_0>>
WC(E/K)[\phi] @>>>
0 \\
&
@VVV
@V \ell VV
@V \ell VV
\\
0 @>>>
E'(K_v) / \phi(E(K_v)) @>\delta>>
H^1(G_v, E[\phi]) @>wc>>
WC(E / K_v)[\phi] @>>>
0
\end{CD}
$$

where I have named some arrows.

For $\xi \in H^1(G_{\bar K / K}, E[\phi])$, and any $v \in M_K$, we can localize (via $\ell$) to get $\xi_v \in H^1(G_v, E[\phi])$. Then we can associate $wc(\xi_v)$ to a homogeneous space, denoted $C_{\xi_v}$. **Question**: Is $C_{\xi_v}$ the same curve for all places $v$?

Context for this question: I was trying to understand how computing the Selmer group reduces to checking whether a certain curve has a rational point. From reading the book, my understanding is that we do:

1. Take $\xi \in H^1(G_{\bar K / K}, E[\phi])$.
2. Localize (via $\ell$) to get $\xi_v \in H^1(G_v, E[\phi])$.
   Then find the homogeneous space $wc(\xi_v)$, which I will denote $C_{\xi_v}$, and check whether it is trivial, which happens if and only if $C_{\xi_v}(K_v) \neq \emptyset$.
3. If $C_{\xi_v}$ is trivial for all $v$, then $\xi$ is an element in the Selmer group.

However, from the examples in Silverman's book, to each $\xi$, he finds **one** homogeneous space $C_\xi$, and checks whether it is trivial for all $v$, i.e. if $C_\xi(K_v) \neq \emptyset$ for all $v$, then $\xi$ is an element of the Selmer group.

Why do this two ways give the same result? If it is too long to explain, a reference to a book will suffice too. P.S. I have searched and found several similar question but they are not asking the same question.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Precisely what do you mean by "the same" - they're completely different objects (curves over $K_v$). If you're asking whether the $C_{\xi_v}$ may be taken to have some equation over $\mathbb{Q}$... that's what the commutativity of the diagram is saying, you just have to check the restriction map of $H^1( \cdot, E)$ behaves with the natural map on $WC$'s.

Comment: Thats not exactly what I meant...I tried to explain more precisely my confusion in the 'context' part: Instead of computing whether $C_{\xi_v}(K_v) \neq \emptyset$ for all $v$, is there some curve $C$ (independent of $v$) so that this computation is equivalent to computing whether $C(K_v) \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: i.e. a curve $C$ so that $[ C_{\xi_v}(K_v) \neq \emptyset \quad \forall v ]\iff [C(K_v) \neq \emptyset \quad \forall v]$

Comment: this is exactly what the commutativity of the above diagram is saying. You take some $\xi$ and you get some $C \in WC(E/K)$. The map on the right is given by viewing $C$ as a curve over $K_v$ instead (since $K \subset K_v$). This is the same as first restricting the cocycle and then getting some curve in $WC(E/K_v)$

Comment: Oh...I did not know that. I thought the map between the two $WC$ groups is super complicated because I thought you have to map from $WC(E/K) \to H^1(G_{\bar K/K}, E) \to H^1(G_v, E) \to WC(E / K_v)$. But now that you said that it makes a lot of sense. I will go back and study it a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Could you make your comment into answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a natural map $WC(E/K) \to WC(E/K_v)$ just by viewing a homogeneous space $C$ for $E$ over $K$ as being defined over $K_v$. The trick is to check that this map agrees with the restriction map on cohomology after we identify $WC(E/k)$ with $H^1(k, E)$.

Following Silverman X3.6 let $p_0 \in C(\bar{K})$ and let $c : \sigma \mapsto p_0^\sigma - p_0$ be the corresponding cocycle representing a class in $H^1(K, E)$. Then $c_v$ is obtained by restricting the domain to $G_{\bar{K}_v/K_v} \subset G_{\bar{K}/K}$. Noting this, and that $p_0 \in C(\bar{K_v})$ we see that (the class of) $c_v$ is precisely the image of $C$ in $H^1(K_v, E)$ when $C$ is viewed as having coefficients in $K_v$.

Recalling that the $\phi$-Selmer group is defined to be the kernel of the map $H^1(K, E[\phi]) \to \prod_v WC(E/K_v)$ then we see that some $\xi \in H^1(K, E[\phi])$ is contained in the $\phi$-Selmer group if (using the notation of OP) $C_\xi$ has a $K_v$-rational point for every place $v$ of $K$.

Comment: Thank you so so much!